# How to perform backup when deleting Site Collection automatically?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, backup

I have requirement which is when user accidentally select delete button for site collection it has to perform backup operation automatically before it deleted is there any WSP solutions available please suggest me.

Many Thanks

Comment: How long do you need to keep that backup available?

Answer (score 2):

I think no need for WSP solutions, the SharePoint already handles this operation by adding the deleted site collection in the `Second stage` when a user accidentally deletes a site collection from **GUI** Central Admin.

---

**How to Restore Deleted the Site Collection**

If you've accidentally deleted a site collection, you can restore it back within `30 days` depends on the Site Quota using [Restore-SPDeletedSite](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh286319%28v=office.16%29.aspx) PowerShell.

Check also [Delete and restore site collections in SharePoint Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/sites/delete-and-restore-site-collections)

---

**But** if you need to keep the backup for a long time (> 30 days), you can handle this through the code, by developing your own **Event Receiver** to perform a backup when a **site collection is being deleted**

[image]

Now, you just need to know How to perform a backup to a site collection

**Backup Site collection C# Code**

```
SPFarm myFarm = SPFarm.Local;
SPServiceCollection myServices = myFarm.Services;
Guid serviceID = new Guid("21d91b29-5c5b-4893-9264-4e9c758618b4");
SPWebService webPubService = (SPWebService)myServices[serviceID];

// Get a reference to the Web application that hosts the 
// site collection.
SPWebApplicationCollection myApps = webPubService.WebApplications;
Guid appID = new Guid("10ea4e6f-ae37-4909-b04f-f516c066bc37");
SPWebApplication myApp = myApps[appID];

// As alternative to the preceding three lines, you can use
// the following when you know the URL of the Web application:
//     SPWebApplication myApp = SPWebApplication.Lookup(url_of_Web_app)

// Get a reference to the Web application's collection of 
// site collections. 
SPSiteCollection mySiteCols = myApp.Sites;

// Back up a specified site collection. 
mySiteCols.Backup(@"http://Server/sites/MySiteCollection", @"\\OtherServer\WSSBackups\SiteCollections\BackupOfMySiteCollection", true);
```

Check also [How to: Programmatically Back Up and Restore a Single Site Collection](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/cc264319(v%3Doffice.14))